# How to inject dependencies that uses intent values with dagger 2?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a situation where my Retrofit classes BaseUrl needs to come from Intent values of an Activity. how to handle that in Dagger2 Modules. i am using Dagger2(dagger:2.13) with DaggerAppCompatActivity.

I have tried storing data in sharedpreference and then using in another activity via dagger 2 modules, but i don't think that is efficent.

Comment: I have created getter and setters as of now in ApplicationContext to store those intent Values and Injected Context in required providers to fetch those intent values

Answer (score 0):

```
Easiest was  to use ApplicationContext Getter and setters e.g. 
public class MaaApplication extends DaggerApplication {

    public String getBaseUrl() {
        return baseUrl;
    }

    public void setBaseUrl(String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }


    private String baseUrl="";
}


public class SampleActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity im {

   @Inject
    IPinPadPresenter pinPadPresenter;


    private void bootStrapApplicationContext()
    {
       try {
           MaaApplication maaApplication=(MaaApplication) getApplicationContext();
String baseUrl= getIntent().getExtras().getString(ConfigConstant.BaseURl);
           maaApplication.setBaseUrl(baseUrl);

       }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
              Timber.e(ex);
      }
    }

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         bootStrapApplicationContext();
    }


@Module
public abstract class SampleActivityModule {
    @Binds
    public abstract Context bindContext(Application application);

   @Named("baseURL")
    @Provides
   static String providebaseUrlDependency(Context context,ITR itr ) {
        String baseUrl =  ((MaaApplication)context).getBaseUrl();

        return baseUrl;
    }
}


}
```